# Удалить гласные буквы

Tags: java

Как удалить гласные буквы?

Я решила двумя способами. В первом способе результат выводится неправильный, а во втором выдает ошибку.

**1 способ:**

```java
public class Vocale {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "i love java";
        String[] voc = {"a", "o", "e", "y", "i"};
        for (int i = 0; i < voc.length; i++)
            if (str.contains(voc[i])) {
                System.out.println(str.replace(voc[i], ""));
            }
    }
}
```

Результат:

```
i love jv i lve java i lov java  love java
```

**2 способ:**

```java
public class Vocale {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("I love java");
        String[] voc = {"a", "o", "e", "y", "i"};
        for (int i = 0; i < voc.length; i++) {
            str.delete(voc[i]); // ошибка
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    }
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем ошибка?

Comment: [тыц](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5)

Comment: `str = str.replace(voc[i], "")`

Answer (score 1):

В первом случае вы каждый раз печатаете исходную строку, без одной главной  буквы, оставляя все другие.

Во втором случае вы изменяете строку, по которой идёт итерация, в итоге она становится короче, что заканчивается обращением к несуществующему элементу (IndexOutOfBoundException или как-то так).

Answer (score 0):

```
  public static String disemvowel(String text) {
  String[] ao ={"a","o","i","u","e","O","I","U","E","A"};
  for(int i=0; i<ao.length;i++){
  text = text.replace(ao[i] ,"");
     }
   return text;
  }
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: А зачем в цикле перебирать все гласные буквы по отдельности, если всё равно будет вызван метод `String::replace`, проще использовать `String::replaceAll`: `public static String disemvowel(String text) {return text.replaceAll("[aeiouAEIOU]", "");}`